# How to import multiple images at once from camera to Samsung tablet

Tags: tablet, images, import

I'm trying to import multiple images (chosen ones) from a Canon camera to a Samsung Tablet 4. The problem is that the upload button is visible only at the beginning when camera is connected and each image can be imported one by one. When I select multiple images the import function dissappears. Tablet is running Android 5.0.2.
I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: It's certainly clear for you but not for us - how do you import images? What saftware do you use?